# Applying multiple filters on store object in extjs

Tags: extjs

I am trying to implement multiple filters on store. Here is my code

```
var record = hg_mGrid.store.getAt(0);
        var switch_id_cust_group=record.get("switch_id_cust_group");
        hg_nmDs.filter([
                        {property: 'name', value: userFilterName},
                        {property: 'switch_id_cust_group', value: switch_id_cust_group}
                        ]);
```

hg_nmDs is a store object, I want to filter its data for name and switch_id_cust_group values. I am not getting any error but none of the two filter criterias are applied.

I also tried this way:

```
var filters=[
                       new Ext.util.Filter({
                        filterFn: function(hg_nmGrid){
                           return hg_nmGrid.get('name') == userFilterName && hg_nmGrid.get('switch_id_cust_group') == switch_id_cust_group;
                        }
                       })
                  ];
        hg_nmDs.filter(filters);
```

But face error "SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action " for line "var filters=[". Could you please help me to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

You have to load the store after you apply the filter.

```
var filters = new Ext.util.Filter({ 
    filterFn: function(hg_nmGrid){ 
        return hg_nmGrid.get('name') == userFilterName && hg_nmGrid.get('switch_id_cust_group') == switch_id_cust_group; 
    } 
}) ; 
store.filter(filters);
store.load(function(){
    console.log('Store should be filtered, when this callback function is called');
})
```

Comment: I face error "SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action" at the line where I have declared filter. var filters=[
                 new Ext.util.Filter({
                  filterFn: function(hg_nmGrid){
                     return hg_nmGrid.get('name') == userFilterName && hg_nmGrid.get('switch_id_cust_group') == switch_id_cust_group;
                  }
                 })
            ];

Comment: store.filter('name', userFilterName);
store.filter('switch_id_cust_group', switch_id_cust_group);
store.load();

Comment: or do it with a function but with different syntax - without these [] brackets: 
var filters= new Ext.util.Filter({ filterFn: function(hg_nmGrid){ return hg_nmGrid.get('name') == userFilterName && hg_nmGrid.get('switch_id_cust_group') == switch_id_cust_group; } }) ;
and then apply the filter... store.filter(longNameFilter)
docs: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.util.Filter